# Initialize empty vector in structure - c++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a `struct`:

```
typedef struct user {
    string username;
    vector<unsigned char> userpassword;
} user_t;
```

I need to initialize `userpassword` with an empty `vector`:

```
struct user r={"",?};
```

What should I put instead of `?`?

Comment: Just say `user r;`. And the `typedef` is unnecessary.

Comment: @chris: this way, userpassword won't contain valid null-terminated C string.

Comment: Code is there only for example ... there will be more values, which i need to initialize with proper values

Comment: @SigTerm and neither will it if you initialize with an empty vector. So?

Comment: @Tomasz, Then make a constructor.

Comment: @chriz: **No**. By default vector has zero length. C string requires at least one byte.

Comment: @SigTerm, Sorry, I thought you were talking about the string there.

Comment: No one mentioned strings here, much less C strings. I mean, other than @SigTerm.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Both `std::string` and `std::vector<T>` have constructors initializing the object to be empty. You could use `std::vector<unsigned char>()` but I'd remove the initializer.

Answer (score 13):

Like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct user
{
    std::string username;
    std::vector<unsigned char> userpassword;
};

int main()
{
    user r;   // r.username is "" and r.userpassword is empty
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 12):

How about

```
user r = {"",{}};
```

or

```
user r = {"",{'\0'}};
```

or

```
user r = {"",std::vector<unsigned char>()};
```

or

```
user r;
```

Comment: 1st didn't wroked, bud the third one works like a charm :) Thank you

Comment: @Tomasz, The first and second are C++11. The last is identical to the third, but much shorter and more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The default vector constructor will create an empty vector. As such, you should be able to write:

```
struct user r = { string(), vector<unsigned char>() };
```

Note, I've also used the default string constructor instead of "".

You might want to consider making user a class and adding a default constructor that does this for you:

```
class User {
  User() {}
  string username;
  vector<unsigned char> password;
};
```

Then just writing:

```
User r;
```

Will result in a correctly initialized user.

Comment: You don't even need the default constructor. The way the OP has it now, it will still do the same thing.